# App crash on launch (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

This sometimes occurs if you manually kill the app and start again. It never happens when you startup via xCode.

**Repro:**

1. Start app1
2. Open the FAS (Fast App Switch) menu and open other app2
3. Do something in another app2 a few minutes
4. Open the FAS (Fast App Switch) menu and force quit app1
5. Relaunch app1

**Result:**
A lauch screen is displayed for several seconds before returned to the springboard.

**Devices:** *iPad2 iOS 8.3.4 / iPad2 iOS 9.0.2*

Crash report isn't saved

**Log:**

```
Nov 10 13:17:46 iPad WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull[9161] <Warning>: ...Creating a BASS device...
Nov 10 13:17:47 iPad WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull[9161] <Warning>: Level Manager: Found 2 stages with 89 levels...
Nov 10 13:17:47 iPad WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull[9161] <Warning>: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EE265319-6E99-419D-A117-AE86C9303EB2/Documents/EleFun Games/Witches Legacy Slumbering Darkness CE/default/profiles\link_30845047142.upf
Nov 10 13:17:57 iPad WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull[9161] <Warning>: Loading resources times: 0.0060 0.0000 0.0170 0.0050 0.1440 0.0410 0.0380 0.1740 0.0333; total: 0.458333
Nov 10 13:17:58 iPad WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull[9161] <Warning>: loading 'data\ui\gui_loaded.xml' time: 0.033333
Nov 10 13:18:01 iPad SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: Forcing crash report of <FBApplicationProcess: 0x19a84cb0; WitchesLegacy5_; pid: 9161> (reason: 1, description: com.bigfishgames.wlsdaapltabletful failed to scene-create after 16.05s (launch took 3.95s of total time limit 20.00s))
Nov 10 13:18:03 iPad ReportCrash[9162] <Error>: assertion failed: 13G36: libsystem_trace.dylib + 15927 [E82A6F2D-873A-39AD-8014-EDEB52248157]: 0x0
Nov 10 13:18:03 iPad Unknown[9162] <Error>: 
Nov 10 13:18:03 iPad ReportCrash[9162] <Warning>: os_activity_diagnostic_for_pid() failed!
Nov 10 13:18:03 iPad SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: Finished crash reporting.
Nov 10 13:18:03 iPad SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection interrupted
Nov 10 13:18:03 iPad SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection invalid
Nov 10 13:18:03 iPad com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.bigfishgames.wlsdaapltabletful[0x9248][9161]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
Nov 10 13:18:03 iPad SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Nov 10 13:18:03 iPad SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.bigfishgames.wlsdaapltabletful[0x9248]' exited abnormally via signal.
Nov 10 13:18:03 iPad UserEventAgent[23] <Warning>: 24604839985416: id=com.bigfishgames.wlsdaapltabletful pid=9161, state=0
Nov 10 13:18:03 iPad mediaserverd[3853] <Notice>: '' com.bigfishgames.wlsdaapltabletful(pid = 9161) setting DiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None
Nov 10 13:18:03 iPad mediaserverd[3853] <Notice>: '' (pid = 9161) setting DiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None
Nov 10 13:18:05 iPad ReportCrash[9162] <Warning>: Report of type '109(109_WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull)' not saved because the limit of 25 logs has been reached
Nov 10 13:18:05 iPad ReportCrash[9162] <Error>: Notice: This report is abbreviated for syslog inclusion because it could not be saved to disk.
    Symbolication may be possible by manually cleaning up and including the Binary Image section of a full report from this same device -- good luck!
Nov 10 13:18:05 iPad ReportCrash[9162] <Error>: Process:             WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull [9161]
    Path:                /var/containers/Bundle/Application/606E5E39-F345-46DD-B10F-BE93B2E88487/WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull.app/WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull
    OS Version:          iOS 9.3.5 (13G36)
Nov 10 13:18:05 iPad ReportCrash[9162] <Error>: Exception Type:  00000020
    Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
    Exception Note:  SIMULATED (this is NOT a crash)
    Highlighted by Thread:  0
Nov 10 13:18:05 iPad ReportCrash[9162] <Error>: Application Specific Information:
    com.bigfishgames.wlsdaapltabletful failed to scene-create after 16.05s (launch took 3.95s of total time limit 20.00s)

    Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 18.230 (user 18.230, system 0.000), 45% CPU 
    Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 11.840, 29% CPU
Nov 10 13:18:05 iPad ReportCrash[9162] <Error>: Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0:
    0   FrontBoardServices              0x23e9fdfc 0x23e9e000 + 7676
    1   FrontBoardServices              0x23eb8f2c 0x23e9e000 + 110380
    2   FrontBoardServices              0x23ea698c 0x23e9e000 + 35212
    3   FrontBoardServices              0x23ea6c4c 0x23e9e000 + 35916
    4   FrontBoardServices              0x23ea6bd4 0x23e9e000 + 35796
    5   UIKit                           0x27612e10 0x26d87000 + 8961552
    6   UIKit                           0x2703591c 0x26d87000 + 2812188
    7   WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x001d317c 0x2e000 + 1724796
    8   UIKit                           0x26e0f784 0x26d87000 + 558980
    9   UIKit                           0x270372d0 0x26d87000 + 2818768
    10  UIKit                           0x2703b284 0x26d87000 + 2835076
    11  UIKit                           0x2704f83c 0x26d87000 + 2918460
    12  UIKit                           0x270387b2 0x26d87000 + 2824114
    13  FrontBoardServices              0x23ec2c06 0x23e9e000 + 150534
    14  FrontBoardServices              0x23ec2ab8 0x23e9e000 + 150200
    15  FrontBoardServices              0x23ec2db8 0x23e9e000 + 150968
    16  CoreFoundation                  0x227e1dfe 0x22726000 + 769534
    17  CoreFoundation                  0x227e19ec 0x22726000 + 768492
    18  CoreFoundation                  0x227dfd5a 0x22726000 + 761178
    19  CoreFoundation                  0x2272f228 0x22726000 + 37416
    20  CoreFoundation                  0x2272f014 0x22726000 + 36884
    21  UIKit                           0x26e08c3c 0x26d87000 + 531516
    22  UIKit                           0x26e03188 0x26d87000 + 508296
    23  WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x001528ec 0x2e000 + 1198316
    24  libdyld.dylib                   0x223d7872 0x223d5000 + 10354
Nov 10 13:18:05 iPad ReportCrash[9162] <Error>: Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x224ac2f8 0x22496000 + 90872
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x223a1d60 0x2238b000 + 93536
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x223a1abe 0x2238b000 + 92862
Nov 10 13:18:05 iPad ReportCrash[9162] <Error>: Thread 2 name:  AURemoteIO::IOThread
    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x224968d0 0x22496000 + 2256
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x224966d4 0x22496000 + 1748
    2   AudioToolbox                    0x24c6c1d8 0x24b46000 + 1204696
    3   AudioToolbox                    0x24c6fa88 0x24b46000 + 1219208
    4   AudioToolbox                    0x24b885ae 0x24b46000 + 271790
    5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2255385a 0x22550000 + 14426
    6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x225537ce 0x22550000 + 14286
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x22551724 0x22550000 + 5924
Nov 10 13:18:05 iPad ReportCrash[9162] <Error>: Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x224aa998 0x22496000 + 84376
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x22552dec 0x22550000 + 11756
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x22553c98 0x22550000 + 15512
    3   WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x001fa40c 0x2e000 + 1885196
    4   WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x00207caa 0x2e000 + 1940650
    5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2255385a 0x22550000 + 14426
    6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x225537ce 0x22550000 + 14286
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x22551724 0x22550000 + 5924
Nov 10 13:18:05 iPad ReportCrash[9162] <Error>: Thread 4:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x224aa998 0x22496000 + 84376
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x22552dec 0x22550000 + 11756
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x22553cd8 0x22550000 + 15576
    3   WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x001fa414 0x2e000 + 1885204
    4   WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x0020dfc6 0x2e000 + 1966022
    5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2255385a 0x22550000 + 14426
    6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x225537ce 0x22550000 + 14286
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x22551724 0x22550000 + 5924
Nov 10 13:18:05 iPad ReportCrash[9162] <Error>: Thread 5:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x224ab864 0x22496000 + 88164
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x22551b34 0x22550000 + 6964
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x22551718 0x22550000 + 5912
Nov 10 13:18:05 iPad ReportCrash[9162] <Error>: Thread 6:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x224ab864 0x22496000 + 88164
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x22551b34 0x22550000 + 6964
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x22551718 0x22550000 + 5912
Nov 10 13:18:05 iPad ReportCrash[9162] <Error>: Thread 7:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x224ab864 0x22496000 + 88164
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x22551b34 0x22550000 + 6964
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x22551718 0x22550000 + 5912
Nov 10 13:18:05 iPad ReportCrash[9162] <Error>: No thread state (register information) available
Nov 10 13:18:05 iPad ReportCrash[9162] <Error>: Error Formulating Crash Report:
    Failed while requesting activity/breadcrumb diagnostics
Nov 10 13:18:05 iPad mediaserverd[3853] <Notice>: 'FigPlayer - 44' (pid = 44) setting DiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None
Nov 10 13:18:06 iPad SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Updating supported commands for now playing application.
Nov 10 13:18:06 iPad SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Updating supported commands for now playing application.
Nov 10 13:18:26 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: AppleHDQGasGauge:stats num_clients=1,num_entries=88746,dl_skip=0,dl_cali=11,dl_over=0,dl_drain=13 ops=5444463,collated=0,bfailures=0,collate_error=0,ioerr=0,timeouts=146 retry16=45672,chf16=4
Nov 10 13:18:26 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: AppleHDQGasGauge:clientLog ld=936291316/d6 le=936296130/e7
Nov 10 13:18:26 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: AppleHDQGasGauge:clientLog 260033309/e4 486542846/T4 486542846/d4 486542846/C4 486545198/S5 486545199/e5 745773952/T5 745773952/d5 745773952/C5
Nov 10 13:18:26 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: AppleHDQGasGauge:clientLog 745774961/S6 745774961/e6 936291316/T6 936291316/d6 936291316/C6 936296130/S7 936296130/e7
Nov 10 13:18:54 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: 1025253.256259 wlan0.A[1340] updateLinkQualityMetrics@1991:Report LQM to User Land 50, fAverageRSSI -71
Nov 10 13:19:04 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: 1025263.273365 wlan0.A[1341] updateLinkQualityMetrics@1991:Report LQM to User Land 100, fAverageRSSI -70
Nov 10 13:19:13 iPad syncdefaultsd[9165] <Notice>: (Note ) SYDPIMAccount: no account (null)
Nov 10 13:19:13 iPad syncdefaultsd[9165] <Notice>: (Note ) SYDBootAccount: no account (null)
Nov 10 13:19:13 iPad syncdefaultsd[9165] <Notice>: (Note ) SYDAlwaysOnAccount: no account (null)
Nov 10 13:19:13 iPad syncdefaultsd[9165] <Notice>: (Note ) SYDAccount: no account
Nov 10 13:19:14 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: 1025273.289861 wlan0.A[1342] updateLinkQualityMetrics@1991:Report LQM to User Land 50, fAverageRSSI -71
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing you could try is to add an All Exceptions point to your project. Therefore in Debug mode your applciation will stop in exception point.

Actual reasons seems to be your main threading is hanging. *com.bigfishgames.wlsdaapltabletful* . **FBApplicationProcess** which is *FrontBoard* process says it couldnt finish 
*applicationDidBecomeActive* or *applicationDidFinishLaunching* methods' execution within 20 seconds time limit. you might look into those methods.